# How to get lastest value based on date in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I tried to find out(guess) current status based on lastest status.

Assume that we have following data frame(it's abbreviation of real data)

```
examineData
ID      Date            Status_Value
A       2012-01-01      100
A       2012-01-10      200
A       2012-02-20      500
B       2012-01-01      1100
B       2012-01-10      1200
B       2012-02-20      1500
C       2012-01-01      2100
C       2012-01-10      2200
C       2012-02-20      2500
```

In above, A,B and C are objects which have status_value. Status_values were examined on the Date.

```
asked
ID      Date
A       2012-01-09
A       2012-02-28
B       2012-02-19
C       2012-01-10
```

But, someone asked about status from A,B and C (it could be less) on specific date.

As you can see, some of `asked$Date` does not match to the `examinData$Date`.

In that case, we decided to get lastest data from `examineData$Date`.

```
ID      Date            Status_Value
A       2012-01-09      100
A       2012-02-28      500
B       2012-02-19      1200
C       2012-01-10      2200
```

Would you give me a sample code? (Speed is important - 1,600,000 rows of `examineData`, 110,000 rows of `asked`)

In addition, There are over 60,000 kinds of ID. And, there are no duplicate date in a same ID in examineData

Comment: ID can be duplicated in `asked` data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
examineData$Date <- as.Date(examineData$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
asked$Date <- as.Date(asked$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

#res <- unlist(lapply(split(examineData, examineData$ID),
#             function(x) { merged <- c(x$Date, asked$Date[asked$ID == unique(x$ID)]) ;
#                     x$Status_Value[which(order(merged) %in% length(merged)) - 1] }))
```

I guess, though, a `data.table` solution might be more efficient than this.

**EDIT** Modified solution, provided -now- that there might be duplicate IDs in `asked`:

```
#dates should, still, be turned into actual dates if they aren't

#function to (m)apply over asked
fun <- function(id, date) 
{ 
 subsetted_examineData <- examineData[examineData$ID == id,]

 merged <- c(subsetted_examineData$Date, date)

 res <- subsetted_examineData$Status_Value[which(order(merged) %in% length(merged)) -1]

 return(res)
}

res <- mapply(fun, asked$ID, asked$Date)

res
#   A    A    B    C 
# 100  500 1200 2200 
cbind(asked, Status_Value = unname(res))                            
#  ID       Date Status_Value
#1  A 2012-01-09          100
#2  A 2012-02-28          500
#3  B 2012-02-19         1200
#4  C 2012-01-10         2200
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you give me an example to use `data.table`?

I could understand completely because of your answer.

Comment: @KeithPark: Unfortunately I am not that familiar with `data.table` to provide a concrete approach, as others here can. PS: I edited my answer to fit your edit in question.

Comment: Thanks for new approach (Now I understand about using `mapply` and `lapply`). Unfortunately, speed issue remains still.

Answer (score 0):

```
sel <- vector()
for(i in 1:length(unique(examineData$ID))){
  id  <- unique(examineData$ID)[i]
  set <- subset(examineData,ID==id)
  dif <- asked[asked$ID==id,"Date"] - set$Date
  dif[dif<0] <- NA
  sel[i] <- row.names(set)[which.min(dif)]
}
examineData[sel,]
```

To get this

```
  ID       Date Status_Value
1  A 2012-01-01          100
5  B 2012-01-10         1200
8  C 2012-01-10         2200
```

You can build in some "corrections" for missing values, but as you have not specified any of, this is the clean way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think looping for entire IDs is not a good way to make(there are over 60,000 IDs...)
I wrote almost same source code.... The biggest reason I asked is because of speed..

Comment: I think `sel[i] <- row.names(set)[which.min(dif)]` must be
`sel[i] <- row.names(set)[which.min(dif)&dif>0]`